# Why my transformation of a for-loop code into a while-loop one failed?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, testing, while-loop, transform

In the process of playing with getting all the odd numbers from 30 to 40 in a javascript's while-loop, I have encountered the problem of not being able to equally transform my for-loop code, which solves this task, into its while-loop counterpart. My while-loop gives out an extra '41'. Was my transformation wrong or while-loop is essentially different from the for-loop in JavaScript?

```
const max = 40;
const min = 30;
for (let i = min + 1; i < max; i += 2) {
  console.log(i);
}
// 31 33 35 37 39


const max = 40;
const min = 30;
let i = min + 1;
while (i < max) {
  console.log(i);
  i += 2;
}
// 31 33 35 37 39 41
```

Yet, if we write down 'console.log('end')' beneath the above while-loop, it will be working correctly. How to explain this?  Is it a bug in the system?

Comment: I think you are mistaken about what the `while` version outputs.  Please provide a complete program that demonstrates what you are saying, and tell us what programming language it is written in ... so that we can compile and run it ourselves.

Comment: The 41 which is getting returned in your while loop is not because of the console.log but after your while loop is getting completed you are getting a returned value as 41. Try commenting the console.log of while loop and execute your code then you will understand.

Comment: (For what it is worth, a simple transliteration of the above into Java shows that the two versions output the same results.)

Comment: @Stephen The same result in Java? Well, in JavaScript they are definately not the same. Two worlds indeed :)

Comment: I updated my answer with a Javascript answer.  I seriously think you are mistakened.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm not a Javascript expert, but after a bit of research, I wonder if this is something to do with what `let` means when there isn't an enclosing `{ ... }` block.  (And it could just be a bug in the JS implementation you are using.)

Comment: @Stephen, no bug in JS implementation. wahab memon and ScratchFilin have noticed this too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging some more output at the end of while loop and it returns me the expected output but with that extra logged statement.

```
var  min = 30, max = 40;
var i = min + 1;
while(i < max){
console.log(i);
i = i + 2;
}
console.log('end');

//31 33 35 37 39 end
```

Comment: Wahab, please, get rid of that: "console.log('end');" in your code and you will get extra '41'. Interesting. Is it a bug in the system?

Comment: @MaksymDudyk, Yes I already mentioned about the extra 41 part  in your questions comments section. Even, am surprised with this behavior of while loop.

Comment: Actually, this is not a bug. We can see this behaviour in for loop also. If you try doing an assignment operation on the last line of for loop then the output of that assignment is printed and this was only noticed on the console of dev tools. If you try your code in here: https://playcode.io, you might not see the extra output.

Comment: Thank you. Let's wait for an assessment of another expert, maybe, in lexical schope to figure this out.